# Disjunctions in a Concept requirement

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

A [requires expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) typically looks like: `requires ( parameter-list(optional) ) { requirement-seq }`.

Is it possible to form a disjunction(||) as a requirement in the sequence without using `requires constraint-expr`. For example something like:

```
template<typename T> concept FooBarExpert = 
requires(T a, T b) { 
    {a.foo(b)} || {a.bar(b)}; // Req 1
    { a.baz() }; // Req 2
    // and onward
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concepts are decomposed in conjunction and disjunction of *atomic-constraints* through a process called *constraint normalization* described in [temp.constr.normal](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal).

Only:

- *logical and* `&&`,
- *logical or* `||`,
- *parenthesized expression* `()`
- and *id-expression of the form `C<A1, A2, ..., An>`, where C names a concept*

are decomposed. All other expressions are *atomic constraints*.

So a *require-expression* is, as a whole, an atomic constraint. In the concept TS, *require-expression* were decomposed but in C++20 they are not. <sub>As far as I remember, I just read all the papers of the c++ committee related to concepts, the reason was that require-expression normalization may cause a complexity explosion that could penalize compilation speed.</sub>

So:

```
requires(T a, T b) { 
    requires requires(T a, T b){a.foo(b)} 
          || requires(T a, T b){a.bar(b)}; // Req 1
    { a.baz() }; // Req 2
    // and onward
};
```

is an *atomic-constraint*. And

```
  requires(T a, T b) { 
    {a.foo(b)} 
    { a.baz() }; // Req 2
     // and onward
    }
|| requires(T a, T b) { 
     {a.bar(b)} 
     { a.baz() }; // Req 2
      // and onward
     };
```

is the disjunction of two atomic constraint. (the two *requires-expression*)

And finaly:

```
     ( requires(T a, T b) { a.foo(b); } || requires (T a, T b) { a.bar(b); } )
  && requires(T a, T b) { a.baz(); /* and onward */};
```

is the conjunction of a disjunction with an atomic constraint.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the same?
Also ,doesn't the experimental clang fork implement the C++20 way of concepts(with some terse syntax missing), because conjunctions inside requires do compile: https://concepts.godbolt.org/z/Qqxn3G

Comment: @tangy Has far as I remember the clang version was announced before the merge of concepts in c++20. The reason why requires expression are not decomposed is given in [p0587r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0587r0.pdf). What do you mean by *Could you provide a reference for the same?*?

Comment: By reference, I meant some link(as you just provided :)) to a page/doc describing what you had written as being part of C++20.
That said in the doc linked, this example is provided under the `requires expression` subtopic:
`template<typename T> concept bool X =
  requires (int x) {
    {f(x)} -> T*;
    {f(x)} -> C*;
  }`

Comment: @tangy It was already there! In the first sentence, the last word, temp.constr.normal is the link you are looking for!

Comment: I'm still learning about this topic, so apologies in advance if Ive misunderstood, but constraint expressions and requires expressions are two distinct concepts right?
I assumed you put the link in the original answer to try and explain how contraint expressions can be combined and normalized. Even CPPReference uses the same description and later provides examples such as `{a + b}; {a - b};` after.

Comment: @tangy `template<typename T> concept bool X = requires (int x) { {f(x)} -> T*; {f(x)} -> C*; }};` defines a concept X that is composed of an atomic-constraint. This is not a disjunction.

Comment: Ah, so then I misunderstood your answer, the part `but requires(T a,T b) { ...} is not a conjunction` to mean that `requires (int x) { {f(x)} -> T*; {f(x)} -> C*; }};`  this syntax is no longer allowed. If you could edit it for a little more clarity?

Comment: @tangy OK so I imagine that you don't know that the terms conjunction and disjunction are only used to establish if a concept subsume an other, which ultimatly has only an influence on overload resolution (or partial specialization ordering). Is it the case? I think I could write a question/answer if this is the case.

Comment: @tangy so reading your last comment I suppose this is the case. No the syntax is still correct... So I am going to write a question answer and bump you.

Comment: No, I did understand about that from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062387/3656081 and some CppCon talks. I just got a little confused by the language in the answer(the concepts syntax jargon is hard to discuss at times as can be seen with `requires requires`)

Comment: @tanguy I made an edit. I hope it is less confusing now.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I was writing nested `requires` for the first time and in case similar to first example I had to put semicolons after `a.foo(b)` and `a.bar(b)` to compile. I'm using `gcc 11.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Define `FooBarExpert` as a conjunction (or disjunction) of the appropriate requires expressions.

```
template<typename T> concept bool FooBarExpert =
( requires(T a, T b) {
    { a.foo(b) };
  } ||
  requires(T a, T b) {
    { a.bar(b) };
  }
) &&
requires(T a, T b) {
  { a.baz() };
};
```