# Understanding what atomic constraints are

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

I've just learnt from a video of a presentation by Saar Raz that the following constraints:

```
template <typename T>
concept C = sizeof(T) > 1;


template <typename T>
concept D = sizeof(T) > 1 && sizeof(T) >= 4;
```

are ambiguous for overloading because the atomic constraints `sizeof(T) > 1` occurring at `C` and `D`, respectively, are not equivalent.

They aren't because the standard says [[templ.constr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#atomic-2):

> Two atomic constraints are *identical* if they are formed from the same *expression* [...]

The key is that *expression* is in italics, referring to the grammar term, which is defined as [[expr.comma]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#1):

> *expression*:
>
> *assignment-expression*
>
> *expression* , *assignment-expression*

I don't understand why an atomic constraint needs to involve an assignment. Why is so?

I must admit that the above code is best written by concept refinement, but I intuitively thought that that way of writing it was correct too.

Comment: The wording is indeed confusing, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2554

Comment: @cpplearner Thanks for the info. Unfortunatelly, I'm even more confused after reading it. When are two atomic constraints the same?

Comment: When they are "expanded" from the same concept (and have the same parameter mapping), AFAIK.

Comment: @cpplearner Therefore the atomic contraints need to be concepts for their equivalence to be tested, right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Note that *assignment-expression* is a grammar term and does not necessary mean that the expression is an assignment.

Comment: I'm wondering how `sizeof(T)` can be greater than or equal to 4, but not greater than 1.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't understand your comment. Are you familiar with concepts and the notion of most constrained? Check this out: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wLOl0CdelaigTfvs

Comment: Can you give me an example of some class `T` for whose `sizeof` is greater than or equal to 4, but not greater then 1. As best as I can figure out, according to the fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe, no such `T` could possibly exist. This concept is nonsensical.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This concept is not mine. I've taken it from the Raz presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nuiwb4Dbefw

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This concept makes sense because this doesn't work: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WS82Sezzmw6b7Ee0

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Saar Raz is the responsible for the implementation of concepts in Clang: https://reviews.llvm.org/p/saar.raz/. He's not a clown. `template <typename T> concept D = C<T> && sizeof(T) >= 4` is perfectly valid and meaningful code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The whole point of my question was whether or not `C<T> && sizeof(T) >= 4` is equivalent to `sizeof(T) > 1 && sizeof(T) >= 4`, even though I strongly prefer the first form. If you were saying in your comments that only concepts participate in constraint subsumption, I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. Anyway, I really appreciate the input. Thanks

Comment: No, the only thing I was saying is that checking if `sizeof(T)` is greater than one and whether or not it is greater than or equal to 4 is meaningless. Whether it's done to define a concept, or for any other purpose. If `sizeof(T)` is at least 4, then there's no way it's less than or equal to 1. Basic laws of math of our shared universe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well `C<T> && sizeof(T) >= 4` effectively does that, and yet you agree it is useful for overload resolution. I obviously realise that `C` is redundant, but it is necessary for the compiler to figure out that `D` is more constrained than `C`. You were insinting so badly on an obvious thing that I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand why an atomic constraint **needs** to involve an assignment. Why is so?

Emphasis mine.

It doesn't *need* to involve an assignment. It's just that *expression* is the top-level grammar term for expressions, that encompasses all the other kinds of expressions. `sizeof(T) > 1` is an *expression*, as is `sizeof(T) >= 4`, as is `sizeof(T) > 1 && sizeof(T) >= 4`.

What this grammar definition means is that an *expression* is either an *assignment-expression* or another *expression* `,` *assignment-expression*. The grammar is hierarchically arranged based on what we consider to be [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

- `,` has the lowest precedence, so the grammar pulls that one out first. That's what happens when we define *expression* recurisvely as *expression* `,` *assignment-expression*
- `=` has the next lowest precedence, so we pull that one out next.
- And then the grammar for *assignment-expression* takes us to *logical-or-expression* (next lowest precedence)
- And then *logical-and-expression*, etc.

An *assignment-expression* need not actually involve an assignment. It's actually any kind of arbitrarily complex expression. All we know about it is that it definitely does not involve a `,` because we already pulled that one out.

---

Separately from all of that, the intent is that two atomic constraints are the same if they are literally the same expression in a source file. That is, constraint subsumption [only applies to `concept`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52062386/2069064).

Comment: So is `sizeof(T) > 1 && sizeof(T) >= 4` an atomic constraint? If so, I don't understand the note in this paragraph: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#atomic-1.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa No it's not, because after undergoing normalization you end up with `sizeof(T) > 1` and `sizeof(T) >= 4` (i.e. a conjunction of the two separate constraints).

Comment: Your last sentence is what I wanted to know. The linked question is also very useful. I guess that the notion of *atomic constraint* is only useful for compiler implementers, while programmers work with *concepts*. Thanks

Comment: This makes a lot more sense when you think of the word "atomic" in the sense of "smallest unit of composition" or "cannot be further decomposed". In this case, given the requirement that it must evaluate to a `bool`, `sizeof(T) > 1` is atomic, whereas `sizeof(T) > 1 && sizeof(T) >= 4` is a conjunction of two atomic expressions.