# Why doesn't Same<T, U> subsume Same<U, T>?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, c++-concepts

In [LWG 3182](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3182), it states that

> The specification of the `Same` concept in 18.4.2 [concept.same]:
>
> ```
> template<class T, class U>
>   concept Same = is_same_v<T, U>;
>
> -1- Same<T, U> subsumes Same<U, T> and vice versa.
> ```
>
> seems contradictory. From the concept definition alone, it is not the case that `Same<T, U>` subsumes `Same<U, T>` nor vice versa.

However, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same),

> ... Commutativity is satisfied, i.e. for any two types `T` and `U`, `is_same<T, U>::value == true` if and only if `is_same<U, T>::value == true`.

Note `Same<T, U>` is defined as `is_same_v<T, U>`, how can `Same<T, U>` does not subsume `Same<U, T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue referred to the standard concept `Same`, which was renamed to `same_as`, and was resolved by
specifying it as [[concept.same]](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.same):

> ```
>  template<class T, class U>
>    concept same-as-impl = is_same_v<T, U>;       // exposition only
>
>  template<class T, class U>
>    concept same_as = same-as-impl<T, U> && same-as-impl<U, T>;
> ```

The reason why the straightforward definition was not symmetric (i.e. `Same<T, U>` did not subsume `Same<U, T>`)
is because [only concepts can be subsumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062386/does-constraint-subsumption-only-apply-to-concepts/52062387#52062387), 
and that's why the exposition-only concept `same-as-impl` is necessary in the spec.