# Why is std::same_as implemented in such a weird way?

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, c++-concepts, language-implementation

[cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) gives a possible implementation of `std::same_as`:

```
namespace detail {
    template<class T, class U>
    concept SameHelper = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}

template<class T, class U>
concept same_as = detail::SameHelper<T, U> && detail::SameHelper<U, T>;
```

Why is it not implemented just as follows:

```
template<class T, class U>
concept same_as = std::is_same_v<T, U> && std::is_same_v<U, T>;
```

or even shorter:

```
template<class T, class U>
concept same_as = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is t handle **subsumption** which only happens with concepts.

With your proposal,

`same_as<T, U>` doesn't subsume `same_as<U, T>`.

Further reading in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Comment: for the last, but the first alternative is equivalent, no?

Comment: `std::is_same_v` is not concept, so `same_as<T, U>` would be atomic constraint with expression  `std::is_same_v<T, U> && std::is_same_v<U, T>`.

Comment: thanks I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062387/4117728) for the details. It is more to read than I have time now, so I put it on my list :)