# Concept subsumption working for functions, but not for structs

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Apologies for potentially wrong title, that is my best guess what is happening.

I was learning some basic concepts and tried this:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
concept eight = sizeof(T) == 8;

template<typename T>
concept basic = std::is_trivial_v<T>;

template<typename T>
requires eight<T>
constexpr void ff(){
    std::cout << "eight" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
requires eight<T> && basic<T>
constexpr void ff(){
    std::cout << "eight and basic" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
requires eight<T>
struct ffs{
};

template<typename T>
requires eight<T> && basic<T>
struct ffs{
};
```

What is insane to me is that I get [error](https://godbolt.org/z/cvhTEzM5s) for struct when same stuff works for functions.

> :29:10: error: requires clause differs in template
> redeclaration requires eight && basic
>          ^ :24:10: note: previous template declaration is here requires eight

It could be that I am just UB+NDRing in both cases but compiler does not mind in first case(not that when I remove structs from code my code seems to run as expected, including distinguishing properly what to invoke based on concepts), but that seems unlikely.

P.S. if somebody wonders why I just don't use requires instead of trivial concepts here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062386/does-constraint-subsumption-only-apply-to-concepts).

Comment: Of course you can't overload class templates. Use partial specialization instead.

Comment: @cpplearner if you can expand on "Of course" in an answer that might be helpful, I always assumed that one of purposes of concepts beside (allegedly) better error messages is template overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading template classes wasn't allowed before concepts, and it still not allowed even with concepts. Use partial specialization:

```
template <typename T>
requires eight<T>
struct ffs {};

template <typename T>
requires basic<T>
struct ffs<T> {};
```

Or with the terse syntax:

```
template <eight T>
struct ffs {};

template <basic T>
struct ffs<T> {};
```

Note that in both cases, the constraints on the primary template automatically apply to all specializations.